# while loop to decrease an instance variable in another class

Tags: java, oop, while-loop

I'm new to java so please be gentle.

So I have a class **mainPlayer** and **badPlayer**, which is a super class to other subclasses.

`mainPlayer` has instance `int health` set to 100

`badPlayer` has a health and that changes depending on the subclasses
Both classes have attacks which are calculated by random numbers

I have made another class `Battle` which contains a `while` loop in a method, but I am trying to figure out how to make it loop until one of the players health is equal to 0?
The aim of the method is to both players attack, if one attack is greater than the other, the player loses health.
The aim is when either of the players gets health <=0 the method to either print "You win" or  "game over". Any help about that?

```
// The Battle class where the while loop is
public static String startFight(BadPlayer b, MainPlayer m) {
    int damage1 = m.maxAttackMain();
    int damage2 = b.maxAttack();

    int mainPlayerHealth = m.getHealth();
    int enemyPlayerHealth = b.getHealth();

    String outcome = " ";

    while(m.health<=0 || b.health<=0) {            
        int decreaseHealth = 20;
        if (damage1 > damage2) {
            mainPlayerHealth =- decreaseHealth;
            mainPlayerHealth--;
            outcome += "game over";
        }

        if (damage1 < damage2) {
            enemyPlayerHealth=-decreaseHealth;
            enemyPlayerHealth--;
            outcome += "You win";
        }
    }
    return outcome;  
}

// The enemy class
public class BadPlayer {
   String description;
   int health;
   protected int award;
   int max_attack;
   int max_block;

   public BadPlayer(String description, int health,  int attack, int block) {
      this.description=description;
      this.health = health;
      this.award=50;
      this.max_attack = attack;
      this.max_block=block;
    }

    Random rnd = new Random();

    public int maxAttack() {
        int rand_int1 = 1 + rnd.nextInt(max_attack);
        return rand_int1;
    }

    public int maxBlock() {
        int rand_int2 = 1 + rnd.nextInt(max_block);
        return rand_int2;
    }

    public int awardCarried(){
        return this.award;
    }

    public String getDesc(){
        return description;
    }

    public int getHealth(){
       return health;
    } 
}

// Class Mainplayer
public class MainPlayer {
    public int health;
    int max_attack;
    int max_block;

    public MainPlayer() {
        this.health=100;
        this.max_attack = 100;
        this.max_block = 150;
    }

    public int getMaxAttack() {
        return max_attack;
    }

    public int getHealth() {
        return health;
    }

    public int getMaxBlock() {             
       return max_block;
    }

    Random random = new Random();

    public int maxAttackMain() {
        int rand_int1 = 50 + random.nextInt(max_attack);
        return rand_int1;
    }

    public int maxBlockMain() {
        int rand_int2 = 1 + random.nextInt(max_attack);
        return rand_int2;        
   }            
}
```

Thank you so much for any help!

Comment: The condition in your while loop seems okay but you have a minor typo: you used `=-` instead of `-=`. Also, you're decrementing local variables mainPlayerHealth but not the actual instance variables?

Comment: @Yani maybe redesign a bit create a function that take a player objet and dec his health and also you can make interface or abstract class for both the players. Also in your classes use some private fields. You can start reading some basics first :) but the main idea is you are not dec the actual values but instead you assign them to a local ones are you dec them. and also e.g. this.award = 50 is a magic number, define some descriptive constants. Start reading some basics first that will be good

Comment: Should this `enemyPlayerHealth =- decreaseHealth` be `enemyPlayerHealth -= decreaseHealth`?